# Revoke GPS permission for a system app on 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gps, permissions

I have a Sony Xperia Miro running Android 4.0.4 - Not Rooted, Stock Firmware. It contains Facebook as system app. Now, i don't want them to track me so i usually have GPS disabled. My question is now: is there a way i can enable GPS but make Facebook think its actually disabled without rooting the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. To do that, you need access to app ops from where you can disable certain operations on a per-app basis. There is no way to do this right now without rooting your device.

Comment: too bad, means i cannot use GPS :/